# Is there utility for windows that makes changing lots of folder icons quickly?

Tags: windows, software-rec

Is there utility for windows that makes changing lots of folder icons quickly?

more specifically

app that utilizes drag n drop where i can drag .ico (icon file) onto a folder to use it as the icon?

Answer (score 1):

easiest i've found was jfolder for folders and qicon changer for apps

here is [a link to jfolder on a site called soft112.com](http://jfolder.soft112.com/download.html)

here is [a link to qicon  changer](http://www.softpedia.com/get/Desktop-Enhancements/Icons-Related/QIcon-Changer.shtml)

Comment: Please expand this answer, provide links and explain what these programs are.

Comment: Explaining *how* to use these and what it accomplishes would make this a better answer.

Comment: I guess it's fairly straight forward to use a program whose purpose is to change icons. And it's not hard for anybody reading the question to find, particularly the second program which is on softpedia, a standard site. I don't think this answer was very flawed. The algorithm might not have liked it. I suppose if you couldn't be bothered with any commentary then best thing would've been to make it a comment.